# Bump API 3.0 Crash in device with Xcode 4.1

Tags: ios, bump

I am using Xcode 4.1 with iOS SDK 4.3

When executing the line below, the app crashes in device but not in Simulator.

```
    [BumpClient configureWithAPIKey:@"MYAPIKEY" andUserID:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]];
```

There is no crash log, but the execution stops at above line saying "Thread 1:Program received signal: "SIGSYS"

Answer (score 2):

As I can see you are using configure API key with BumpClient object. Actually there is requirement to create object of BumpAPI and key would be set like that

```
    api = [BumpAPI sharedInstance];
    [api configAPIKey:@"69d6db94740a4e9e8e9ba98ey0e64c74"];
    [api configUIDelegate:self];
    [api configDelegate:self];
    [api requestSession];
```

here api is object of BumpAPI and configure API keys as mentioned After that session is requested .

```
   [[BumpAPI sharedInstance] simulateBump];
```

Simulate Bump starts the bump action on device. So there is only requirement to attach bump delegate to self not to device.